# Hiding '//*Form' in output cell labels?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, style

Is there a way to hide the '//form' part of Output cell labels but keep the Input cell labels the same?

For example, I'd like to keep *"In[2]:="* but get rid of the *"TreeForm="* here:

[image]

Comment: Using [`$POST`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$POST.html), you could wrap all output in an extra [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html): `$Post = Row[{#}] &;`

Comment: I like `$PrePrint=SequenceForm` better, so that `Out[n]` doesn't include the wrapper.

Comment: You could remove these from `$OutputForms` (after `Unprotect`ing it), but that would also have the unfortunate side effect of not stripping these wrappers from the value assigned to `Out[...]`.  I do not know if there will be any more serious consequences. I guess there is a reason why it is `Protected`.

Comment: The problem is that the new statement `Out[n]:=` will not be true.